# MinGW GCC Toolchain missing from Eclispe CDT when using "Convert to a C/C++ Project"

Tags: eclipse, mingw

I'm having an issue when I try to convert an existing project in Eclipse Mars using File -> New -> Other -> C/C++ -> Convert to a C/C++ Project (Adds C/C++ Nature).  The MinGW GCC toolchain is not present.

My project shows under "Candidates for conversion" but when I select "Makefile project" for Project Type and I uncheck :Show Project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the platform" my only option for toolchains is "GNU Autotools Toolchain."

I've made sure the MinGW install is set in my path variable as well as MINGW_HOME.

However, if I create a new C++ project the MinGW GCC toolchain is present and I'm able to create the a new project.

Eclipse Info: 
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue stemmed from my workspace's metafiles.  I must have done something incorrectly when I initially pulled the project on my PC.

I did the following steps and solved my problem:
- Deleted local copy of project in version control
- Deleted the imported project from eclipse
- Cleared eclipse's workspace files that was holding onto meta data for the project
- Pulled the project fresh to my PC
- Re-imported the project using eclipse 
- Converted to a C/C++ Project and MinGW GCC was available